# Transfer changes from "master" to my branch

Tags: git, merge, rebase, pull-request, pull

Network graph in my repository is as follows:

```
M--------------M
|              ↑
├-->1---1---1--┘
|
└-->2---2
```

Where: `M` are pushed commits on `master`, `1` are pushed commits on `branch-1` and `2` are pushed commits on `branch-2`.

As you can see, commits from `branch-1` were pushed, requested for "pull request" and merged into `master`.

I'm on `branch-2` and I work under my tasks.

I need to have source code from master to finish them.

First question: What should I do to transfer source code from master to my `branch-2`?

I was considering:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

or:

```
git pull origin --rebase master
```

Second question: What should I do if I have local changes after the pushed second commit on `branch-2` and I would like to do the same as above?

Comment: Pushing and merging/rebasing are very different things.

Comment: If you want to get the changes that are in the master branch, and branch-2 isn't being used by anyone else, I'd suggest rebasing your branch-2 onto master. I'd also suggest committing your changes first.

Comment: @OliverRadini, thank you for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update* - I forgot to address the 2nd question

---

*First Question*

You can either merge `master` into your branch, `rebase` your branch to a later commit on master, or `cherry-pick` the commits that introduce the changes you need.  Which to do depends on what kind of workflow you (and your team, if applicable) want to use.

The advantage of `merge` is that it doesn't rewrite any history and it doesn't duplicate any commits.  In some ways it's the simplest operation, but it does create what many consider to be a more complex history.  (There is no one objective answer to what sort of history is "better"; it depends how you want to use the history.)  If you decide to merge you could do something like

```
git checkout branch-2
git merge master
```

This assumes your local master is up to date.  If it's not you could either update it, or do

```
git fetch
git checkout branch-2
git merge origin/master
```

By default, `pull` is a shortcut for "`fetch` and `merge`", so you also could do

```
git checkout branch-2
git pull origin/master
```

Personally I don't typically use `pull` this way; I use it only when I'm updating a branch from its own upstream.  But still it's a valid option.

The advantage of `rebase` is that it avoids the merge commit and creates a more linear history that some people prefer, and often doesn't require you to keep duplicate commits around (i.e. it creates copies of commits, but you can often discard the originals when you're done).  The history is not as reflective of how the software was really written, and in particular it may contain commits that don't build cleanly even if you otherwise maintained a "clean checkin" policy.  And it is a history rewrite; if the branch you `rebase` has already been shared with others (i.e. it's been `push`ed to the origin at any point), then this may cause problems[1].

If you decide to do a rebase, you could say

```
git rebase master branch-2
```

As with merge, you could first `fetch, and update`master`from its upstream or substitute`origin/master`for`master`as needed.  You can also configure`pull`to do a`rebase`instead of a`merge`, but this is not considered a "safe" configuration and you should only do it if you're very comfortable with all of the operations involved.

The advantage of `cherry-pick` is that it avoids creating merge commits and also avoids any history rewrite.  However, it creates duplicate commits, which can also complicate history a bit.  It may be a good option if all the changes you want are introduced to `master` in a small number of commits.  If you're eventually going to `merge` your branch back to `master`, it could increase the chance of merge conflicts, though they shouldn't be too hard to correct.  If you eventually `rebase` the branch onto `master`, that shouldn't be an issue (because `rebase` has specific protection against conflicts introduced by `cherry-pick`.)  If you choose this approach, first identify the commits you need to copy, then

```
git checkout branch-2
git cherry-pick <commit>
```

where `<commit>` is an expression that resolves to the commit you need - such as its commit ID (hash) or a relative expression (for example `master~2` would be the 2nd parent - i.e. 3rd to last commit - on the `master` branch).

*Second Question*

If you have uncommitted local changes, you will want to be a little careful.  The most effective protections `git` has against data loss don't apply to the working tree copy.  `git` will *generally* try to avoid deleting data in the work tree, unless the command you give implies that you want it to overwrite the work tree.  (Unfortunately sometimes it isn't obvious which commands will work like that.)

So the safest thing to do, before the (merge or rebase or cherry-pick), stash your changes.

```
git stash
```

And afterwards, restore them

```
git stash pop
```

Be aware that this may result in merge conflicts (since your local changes could affect the same hunk of code as the commits you added to your branch).  Also, by default this unstages all of your local changes.  If you need to keep the staged changes and unstaged changes separate, you can say

```
git stash --index pop
```

But, in the event of a merge conflict during the `pop`, the command will fail when given the `--index` option.  (At that point, you'd either proceed without the `--index` option, or go through more involved hoops to apply your changes.  The "more involved hoops" I can go into if needed.)

---

[1] In general if you are going to do a history rewrite of a shared branch, you need to coordinate with everyone who has a copy of the branch.  If you don't, then their natural attempts to deal with the errors they get might undo the rewrite.  People object that in distributed repos that could be impractical; if it's impractical, then you shouldn't rewrite the history.  See the `git rebase` docs under "Recovering from upstream rebase" for more information.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: Perfectly logical explanation :) Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The operations you are trying to do are best accomplished through merging or rebasing.

Pushing and pulling are merely incidental to what you're trying to do. They just make sure that your local copy of the repo is synced up with what is on the remote. All the actual operations are done purely locally. If you have local commits on your branch, they will be used.

To get master into your branch, you can either rebase onto master, or merge master in. If you are working on a personal branch and you have permission to force-push non fast forward commits, rebase will keep your history cleaner:

```
git rebase master
git push -f
```

If on the other hand you are working collaboratively, or don't have force push permissions, use merging:

```
git merge master
git push
```

Both operations above assume that you are on your branch of interest. In both cases, the remote branch does not figure into the first part of the operation in any way. The different push options just take into account whether or not your remote can be fast forwarded from the local branch after the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! ;)

Comment: No problem. If this works for you, feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Comment: "rebase will keep your history cleaner" is definitely a matter of opinion.  `rebase` often results in histories of commits that won't build and pass tests, which is not objectively cleaner as it interferes with potential future debugging (i.e. `git bisect`)

Comment: @Mark. I've always been a fan of merging myself. That's the excuse that I generally hear for preferring rebase, but it's only really robust if you squash as well.